# Zombie Detected - But function never called

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

**What i have Done?**

In one of my `UIViewController` child i have implemented `UITableView` and have implemented the necessary `UITableViewDelegate` functions.

**What i am Facing?**

The issue i am facing is that i get EXC_BAD_ACCESS in Application whenever i relaunch the Controller and tap on Any cell.

**What i have Tried?**

I have tried to place breakpoints in the function [didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:) but it never reaches the Breakpoint. I tried Global Exception Breakpoint but it also didn't worked. I checked using the Instruments and found that a zombie is detechted when `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` is called but control doesn't reaches the Function.

[Instruments Zombie Details Image - Photo Bucket Link](http://i1341.photobucket.com/albums/o750/Quamber_Ali/ScreenShot2014-07-17at92157am_zps0f73d344.png)

After Implementing the Given Suggestions in the Comments this is the log that i have received

```
*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x023e11e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01fc98e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02393abc -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:] + 844
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x02393760 -[__NSArrayM addObject:] + 64
    4   UIKit                               0x00bf5782 -[UITableViewIndex _displayTitles] + 1071
    5   UIKit                               0x00bf58a8 -[UITableViewIndex _cacheAndMeasureTitles] + 171
    6   UIKit                               0x00bf6213 -[UITableViewIndex sizeThatFits:] + 131
    7   UIKit                               0x00a18bbc -[UITableView _updateIndexFrameSuppressingChangeNotification:] + 513
    8   UIKit                               0x00a189b6 -[UITableView _updateIndexFrame] + 41
    9   UIKit                               0x00a19a5f -[UITableView _updateIndex] + 649
    10  UIKit                               0x00a336f7 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 295
    11  UIKit                               0x009b3964 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    12  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01fdb82b -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    13  QuartzCore                          0x002ba45a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    14  QuartzCore                          0x002ae244 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    15  QuartzCore                          0x002ae0b0 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    16  QuartzCore                          0x002147fa _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    17  QuartzCore                          0x00215b85 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    18  QuartzCore                          0x00216258 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x023a936e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x023a92bf __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x02387254 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x023869d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x023867eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x0381a5ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x0381a42b GSEventRun + 104
    26  UIKit                               0x00944f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    27  MyApplication                       0x00001f9c main + 76
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x034b3701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: On cell selection what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: CountryListViewController object has been released and you are trying to access this object, thats the reason of crash

Comment: Goto Product->Scheme->Edit Scheme->Run (from left)->Diagnostic tab check mark `log exceptions`. and see if it shows some error message.

Comment: @SuryakantSharma. Lets say just an NSLog. If function is not called it doesn't matter what is in the function

Comment: @Ritu you might be right. But that issue should be in Non-Arc project. Its an arc based project so while the view is still displayed why would this happen?

Comment: @NeverHopeless Will Try and let you know

Comment: Can you please share `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` code?

Comment: please explain what RegisterViewController and CountryListViewController are. In your image, you tapped the tableView of  RegisterViewController, but jombie indicate CountryListViewController..

Comment: I think, you have created a local object for CountryListViewController, please make a class object of CountryListViewController, that may be the reason.

Comment: I'm surprised nobody has mentioned enabling zombie objects on the diagnostics tab of the edit scheme page.  This generally gives you a lot more context into the zombie object itself and what message it was sent.  From reading the description is it possible that the zombie object is the tableviews delegate?

Comment: I have checked after enabling all the suggestion this is what i got in My console '-[CountryListViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:]: message sent to deallocated instance'

Comment: Please check the Edits

Comment: is the issue resolved?

Comment: Will you please give me the code how you are presenting your CountryListViewController. Please check my answer from the question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482650/autorotation-crash-in-ios

Comment: @user3675059 can you post the code , i think you loss the nsarray , because may be you have defined it as weak (should be strong). this exception tells that you are trying to add a object to array , which is deallocated.

Comment: How can you present Your viewcontroller? Or it will subview on any other viewcontroller?

Comment: Now you are trying to insert nil object into array, which causes the crash. Check what you are trying to add, maybe it has weak reference to it while should have strong one.

Comment: What is your code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method ?

Comment: @user3675059, such problems are often encountered in my practice. Hm. Looks like your data source returns a nil cell.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty clear from all the logs and Zombie images that you are accessing the deallocated `CountryListViewController`. Keep track on the `CountryListViewController` and check it is available while you processing your table-view operations.

The better option is, Go to Xcode Menu `Product->Scheme->Mange Schemes->Edit (left bottom)-> Debug-> Diagnostics -> Check all the options -> then Run the project`.

This will be the Lighthouse to discover your crash.